# Tikz computes the wrong coordinates

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikzmath

I'm trying to calculate some coordinates to get an accurate tikz figure. I managed to do it by hardcoding some coordinates, but since I have to repeat the process for many of them, I thought it would be better to write a function. The problem is that, although I have no errors, the coordinates are wrong and I do not understand why. This is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shapes.misc,math}

\begin{document}

\tikzmath{
\u1=1/3;
\v1=1/3;
}

\tikzset{cross/.style={cross out, draw=black, minimum size=4*(#1-\pgflinewidth), inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt},
%default radius will be 1pt. 
cross/.default={1pt}}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  declare function={map(\xi,\eta,\u,\v,\w) = (1-\xi-\eta)*\u+\xi*\v+\eta*\w;}
]

\begin{scope} []

% define internal node coordinates
\coordinate (X1) at (-1.66,0.3012);
\coordinate (X2) at (0.1332,0.9123);
\coordinate (X3) at (-0.6667,0.2123);

% draw triangle
\draw [] (X1) -- (X2) -- (X3) -- cycle;

\path let \p1 = (X1), \p2 = (X2), \p3 = (X3) in node[cross] at ({map(1/3,1/3,-1.66,0.1332,-0.6667)},{map(1/3.,1/3.,0.3012,0.9123,0.2123)}) {};
%\path let \p1 = (X1), \p2 = (X2), \p3 = (X3) in node[cross] at ({map(\u1,\v1,-1.66,0.1332,-0.6667)},{map(\u1,\v1,0.3012,0.9123,0.2123)}) {};
%\path let \p1 = (X1), \p2 = (X2), \p3 = (X3) in node[cross] at ({map(1/3,1/3,\x1,\x2,\x3)},{map(1/3.,1/3.,\y1,\y2,\y3)}) {};
%\path let \p1 = (X1), \p2 = (X2), \p3 = (X3) in node[cross] at ({map(\u1,\v1,\x1,\x2,\x3)},{map(\u1,\v1,\y1,\y2,\y3)}) {};

\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The cross is properly placed at the center of the triangle but when I use the function (commented line) the cross is moved elsewhere. The first two commands work fine, so I managed to use `\u1` and `v1`, but then the last two won't work, so I'm clearly doing something wrong with the `let` syntax. I could not find anything related to this in the Tikz manual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that `\x1`,`\x2` are in `pt` in place of `cm`. So one way to solve the problem is to convert them back to `cm`. I have defined and used a function that do that.

```tex
\documentclass[tikz,border=7pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shapes.misc,math}

\tikzmath{
  \u1=1/3;
  \v1=1/3;
}

\tikzset{
  cross/.style={
    cross out,
    draw=black,
    minimum size=4*(#1-\pgflinewidth),
    inner sep=0pt,
    outer sep=0pt
  },
  %default radius will be 1pt.
  cross/.default={1pt},
  declare function={cm(\t) = \t*0.03514598;}, % 1pt = 0.03514598 cm
  declare function={map(\xi,\eta,\u,\v,\w) = (1-\xi-\eta)*\u+\xi*\v+\eta*\w;}
}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    % define internal node coordinates
    \coordinate (X1) at (-1.66,0.3012);
    \coordinate (X2) at (0.1332,0.9123);
    \coordinate (X3) at (-0.6667,0.2123);

    % draw triangle
    \draw [] (X1) -- (X2) -- (X3) -- cycle;

    \path let \p1 = (X1), \p2 = (X2), \p3 = (X3)
      in node[cross]
      at ({map(1/3,1/3,-1.66,0.1332,-0.6667)},{map(1/3.,1/3.,0.3012,0.9123,0.2123)}) {};
    \path let \p1 = (X1), \p2 = (X2), \p3 = (X3)
      in node[cross, red]
      at ({map(\u1,\v1,-1.66,0.1332,-0.6667)},{map(\u1,\v1,0.3012,0.9123,0.2123)}) {};
    \path let \p1 = (X1), \p2 = (X2), \p3 = (X3)
      in node[cross, blue, very thin]
      at ({map(1/3,1/3,cm(\x1),cm(\x2),cm(\x3))},{map(1/3.,1/3.,cm(\y1),cm(\y2),cm(\y3))}) {};
    \path let \p1 = (X1), \p2 = (X2), \p3 = (X3)
      in node[cross, orange, ultra thin]
      at ({map(\u1,\v1,cm(\x1),cm(\x2),cm(\x3))},{map(\u1,\v1,cm(\y1),cm(\y2),cm(\y3))}) {};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**HINT:** If you want to calculate the barycentric coordinates of points, there are better ways to do it.

Comment: Thanks for the swift reaction. I moved the `cm` inside the `map` function to simplify the implementation later. Regarding the centroid, this was just an example, I need to find the coordinates of Gauss integration points for high order polynomials. Thanks again for the help!